# Jquery setTimout ruins all func

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function on JQuery to show my tooltips, but 
when i try to add a timeout to make some delay before showing a tooltip nothing  works(((

```
$('.help').mouseover(function(){
  setTimeout(function{ //this is timeout if i delete this - evrthng goes well
    $(this).find('div').stop().fadeIn(900);
    var top = $(this).position().top;
    var left = $(this).position().left;
    var height = $(this).find(".tip").height();
    $(this).find(".tip").css('top', top-height);
    $(this).find(".tip").css('left', left)
  }, 1000);
});
```

Please tell me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: `setTimeout(function{` should be `setTimeout(function(){` for a start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside `setTimeout()`, `this` refers to `Window` instead of to `$('.help')`.  Try this:

```
$('.help').mouseover(function(){
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(that).find('div').stop().fadeIn(900);
        var top = $(that).position().top;
        var left = $(that).position().left;
        var height = $(that).find(".tip").height();
        $(that).find(".tip").css('top', top-height);
        $(that).find(".tip").css('left', left)
    }, 1000);
});
```

Take into account that [`setTimeout()` is a method of Window](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp).

Comment: Thank you! This helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot the () after function and you're missing a semicolon at your last line. Try this:

```
$('.help').mouseover(function(){
   setTimeout(function(){ //this is timeout if i delete this - evrything goes well
      $(this).find('div').stop().fadeIn(900);
      var top = $(this).position().top;
      var left = $(this).position().left;
      var height = $(this).find(".tip").height();
      $(this).find(".tip").css('top', top-height);
      $(this).find(".tip").css('left', left);
   }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

or just proxy this:

```js
setTimeout($.proxy(function(){
  ...
}));
```

;)